# Handle two variables one database entry

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have a row for user like so

id username owns

I'm going to make a form to designate a few details such as what a user owns...

For example they could own a bike,truck,car ect. What would be the best way to approach this without creating a new column for each possession? or is creating a new column for each possession the way to go?

There is no set number of possessions.

Comment: you could add what user owns in your 'owns' field..?

Comment: you can add owns in your owns field by separating each item as comma (,)

Comment: So sorry. If they own multiple objects. So they could have both a bike and a truck.

Comment: @kalpit can you give me a simple example of what you mean?

Comment: if user owns bike & truck then your owns field would contain value bike,truck

Comment: Two questions for you @kalpit . First how would you get the "," bettewen them and the second is how could you output that...say in a dropdown?

Comment: for ",", store owns field result in array temp and use implode() and store it in db or else you have to go for 2nd normal form by creating separate table for it.

Comment: how your getting owns field means using checkbox or something else?

Comment: user text field @kalpit

Comment: @kalpit Adding multiple values 1 column would violate the 1NF. This is not a good idea.

Comment: @Chris then you can do directly by concatenating those text fields in variable and store it directly. no need to create array and implode().

Answer (score 2):

How about creating three tables.  The first would be for the user:

```
-------------
| id | user |
-------------
| 1  | Jim  |
| 2  | Tom  |
| ...| etc  |
-------------
```

And the second would contain products:

```
----------------
| id | product |
----------------
| 1  | Truck   |
| 2  | Bike    |
| 3  | Car     |
----------------
```

And the 3rd would link them together:

```
------------------------
| user_id | product_id |
------------------------
|   1     | 1          |  # Jim owns a truck
|   1     | 2          |  # Jim also owns a bike
|   2     | 3          |  # Tom owns a Car
------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a strategy called `2nd normal form` you create another table called `user_own`

with fields `user_id, own_item`

then you can insert records into the second table per each item the user-owns.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new table called userPossessions or something of the like and adding a foreign key to the first column that will constrain to the user id. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE userPossessions (
userID int(11) NOT NULL,
posession varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userID),
CONSTRAINT userid_const FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That way you can add as many possessions (or "owns") to that table and you can easily join the two tables together on the user ID's.